# Клиент C# для передачи сообщений SOAP with Attachment

Tags: c#, soap

Пишу клиент на C# для отправки SOAP сообщений с вложениями. Подключив WSDL, не удается сгенерированными методами это сделать. Нашел на форумах пример для отправки SOAP сообщения без использования WSDL:

```
private static string GetResponseSoap(string _url, string _method, string _soapEnvelope)
    {
        _url = _url.Trim('/').Trim('\\'); // в конце адреса удалить слэш, если он имеется
        WebRequest _request = HttpWebRequest.Create(_url);
        //все эти настройки можно взять со страницы описания веб-сервиса
        _request.Method = "POST";
        _request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        _request.ContentLength = _soapEnvelope.Length;
        _request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "/{_method}");
        // пишем тело
        StreamWriter _streamWriter = new StreamWriter(_request.GetRequestStream());
        _streamWriter.Write(_soapEnvelope);
        _streamWriter.Close();
        // читаем тело
        WebResponse _response = _request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader _streamReader = new StreamReader(_response.GetResponseStream());
        string _result = _streamReader.ReadToEnd(); // переменная в которую пишется результат (ответ) сервиса
        return _result;
    }
```

Прошу подсказать пример, но для отправки сообщений с вложением. Какие .Net классы использовать? Как реализовать такой клиент?

Comment: Может всё же лучше разобраться с WSDL?

Comment: В `_soapEnvelope` что содержится? Сервис ожидает XML.

Comment: Самое главное: что происходит при выполнении показанного метода? Выбрасывается исключение? Приходит неверный ответ? Или что?

Comment: Структура WSDL не содержит свойства-вложения. Данный метод работает, отправляет SOAP конверт и получает ответ. В  _soapEnvelope помещается текст XML.